# Using FFMPEG filters directly in Web Audio API AudioWorklet

Tags: ffmpeg, web-audio-api, libav, audio-worklet

I am trying to leverage the vast numbers of audio filters that FFMPEG has and see if I can use them directly in a custom AudioWorklet so I dont have to reinvent the wheel for each and every filter. One option I came across was to convert the AVFilter library to WASM and write a wrapper class to call the library functions.
https://dev.to/alfg/ffmpeg-webassembly-2cbl

But I am looking for a solution where the data can be piped to the filter and the output passed instantaneously to the other audio worklet nodes so the effect can be heard without a delay.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Audio Worklet Design Pattern](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/audio-worklet-design-pattern).  The FFMPEG modules would be compiled to WebAssembly modules, and the AudioWorklet could communicate directly with the WASM modules, ideally through a [`SharedArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) for low-latency audio processing.

For browsers that don't support SharedArrayBuffer, [`MessagePort.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessagePort/postMessage) could be used, passing the `Transferrable` ArrayBuffers.